# unexpected token - doing recursive to print christmas tree

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's wrong with my code below? Couldn't spot any problem on my end. https://jsfiddle.net/rz8y6vc7/

```
function pyramid(n, row, level = '') {
  if (row === n) {
    return;
  }

  if (level.length === 2 * n - 1) {
    return pyramid(n, row + 1);
  }

  const midpoint = Math.floor((2 * n - 1) / 2);
  let add;
  if (midpoint - row <= level.length && midpoint + row => level.length) {
    add = '#';
  } else {
    add = ' ';
  }
  pyramid(n, row, level + add);
}

pyramid(4)
```

Got error on this line.`if (midpoint - row <= level.length && midpoint + row => level.length) {`

Comment: `=>` is not an operator.

Comment: @elclanrs fixed that but got maximum stack error https://jsfiddle.net/40Lj4zk1/

Answer (score 0):

`=>` is not an operator in JavaScript.

You may be thinking of `<=`, which is the smaller-than-or-equal-to operator.

You may read more about this particular operator here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Less_than__or_equal_operator

Answer (score 0):

The problems with your code are:

1. You are not printing the output into the browser, I am using `document.write()` to show the output.
2. White space is not preserved in HTML, you can insert the text into a `pre` tag where the white spaces are preserved.
3. You are getting `max stack exceeded error` because you are not initializing the variable `row`. You can initialize this variable the same way you initialized `level` variable!

Please refer the below code snippet where it works and let me know if you face any issues implementing!

```js
function pyramid(n, row = 0, level = '') {
  if (row === n) {
    return;
  }

  if (level.length === 2 * n - 1) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += "\n";
    return pyramid(n, row + 1);
  }

  const midpoint = Math.floor((2 * n - 1) / 2);
  let add;
  if (midpoint - row <= level.length && midpoint + row >= level.length) {
    add = '#';
  } else {
    add = ' ';
  }
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += add;
  pyramid(n, row, level + add);
}

pyramid(4)
```

```html
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Comment: @Casa Does this answer help you? if not, what is lacking?